# Using $server in a Puppet template?

Tags: puppet

I am trying to use the Puppet server as a variable in my puppet template like this: `<%= $settings::server %>`. But I get an error:

```
undefined method `server' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I use the configured Puppet server as a variable in my templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use Puppet syntax variable lookups in ERB, and that won't work. ERB is not Puppet, and the two syntaxes are not compatible.  Instead, you want to assign the value to a simple (non-namespaced) variable in your manifest, and then use *that* variable in your ERB.  You *can* use `scope`, as kashani suggests, but nobody else (or you in 6 months) will know WTF you're doing and why it's important.

Comment: I'm not a fan creating local variables when you have scoped ones which indicate origin, but to each their own. :-) Admittedly I think settings classes are far more trouble than they are worth and a poor substitute for Hiera or other external data lookup.

Comment: Puppet scoping is insane, and they're in the process of reworking it for the next version, which will make everything change again.  Local variables and composition are the only sane way to do Puppet manifests.

Comment: Thanks, after working with Puppet more, I understand what is happening now and why this answer is a little more safer down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It's a bit wordier, but should be the most reliable. FWIW, removing the $ should also work, but might not after Puppet 2.7.

```
<%= scope.lookupvar('settings::server') %>
```